# VirtualBox Bridged Connectivity not working Kubuntu 22.10

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

I cannot get my Virtual Box 7.0 "bridged adapter" to work on my laptop (Kubuntu 22.10).
I have a project that I need to submit, but I cannot move forward until I fix this.
This affects all my guest machines.

These are my guest virtual machines:

[image: Guest Virtual Machines]

1. The 'Greenbone-Enterprise-TRAIL' virtual machine needs to be setup as 'bridge' because I am performing a vulnerability scan against another VM, 'analysis_image_final' which is an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine.
2. Here is 'Greenbone-Enterprise' link of the website with instructions how to setup on VirtualBox >> [enter link description here](https://www.greenbone.net/en/testnow/#toggle-id-4)
3. Below are the network settings on my Greenbone-Enterprise Trail on VirtualBox:
   [image: GB Settings]
   **`'wlan0'` is my wireless adapter.**

[image: GB Settings 2]

`Promiscuious mode` picture below:

[image: Promiscuious mode]

I have tried researching previous articles but they didnt fix my issue:

1. [Virtualbox bridged adapter not working ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985880/virtualbox-bridged-adapter-not-working-ubuntu)
2. [VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04 - Bridge adapter not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722512/virtualbox-ubuntu-14-04-bridge-adapter-not-working)
3. [Kubuntu 16.10 - VirtualBox not working correctly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854390/kubuntu-16-10-virtualbox-not-working-correctly)

Then, I though maybe it's how my `resolv.conf` or `netplan` file setup

Here is my `resolv.conf` file below:

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

Here is my `01-network-manager-all.yaml` file below:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

I found this article that I though this will fix my issue:

1. [How to set wlan0 active as default in /etc/network/interfaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244523/how-to-set-wlan0-active-as-default-in-etc-network-interfaces)
2. [/etc/network/interfaces to connect Ubuntu to a wireless network](https://linuxconfig.org/etcnetworkinterfacesto-connect-ubuntu-to-a-wireless-network)

When I made changes to my `resolv.conf` file, my BIOS would not load my wireless adapter after reboot.

I need help

***Update***

output for `nmcli connection show`

[image: nmcli connection show]

Comment: Because you very likely don't have a bridge connection actually in place, please add output of `nmcli connection show`

Comment: @NicolasFormichella updated the question with the output

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to

> Note that a bridge cannot be established over Wi-Fi networks operating in Ad-Hoc or Infrastructure modes. This is due to the IEEE 802.11 standard that specifies the use of 3-address frames in Wi-Fi for the efficient use of airtime.

From [Red Hat support site](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/ch-configure_network_bridging)

Solution : Get an Ethernet connection to that computer if practically possible, then follow the following [guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/network_bridge#With_NetworkManager) and set `bridged interface` to whatever name you got it

Comment: I found this question on VirtualBox forum website: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=96608#p468775

Answer (score 0):

**I figured out the "My" solution!**

Here is the link: [How To Use Your Wireless Adapter With VirtualBox Bridge Mode](https://www.revolutionweb.com.au/computer-security/use-wireless-adapter-virtualbox-bridge-mode/)

> The bridged network adapter has its own MAC address (the hardware
> address of the card), although physically the bridged adapter is on
> the same card. The thing about network adapters is that they are not
> limited to a single IP address.
>
> Also, a thing I wasn’t aware of is that the wifi authentication is in
> fact tied to the MAC address of the network card.
>
> So once I figured this out, the solution at the outset  I said it was
> fairly simple. Set the bridge network address to the mac address of
> the wireless adapter, then assign the Pfsense interface an ip address.
> And hey presto.. it works. Not a bad little bit of troubleshooting if
> I do say so myself.
>
> For those who are newbies to IT, this image may help. This is the
> result of the ifconfig command in linux. The MAC address is
> highlighted. The same command can be used in Windows, although it is
> called ipconfig, and to see the MAC address, you have to use the
> command ipconfig /all.

[image: pic1]

> As I have said, you take the highlighted address and put in in the
> virtual machine settings. Which are found under settings, which you
> can see in the next image. It’s a simple cut and paste, and you’re
> done.

[image: pic2]

This works for me